# Update DataGridView with dataview

Tags: database, datagridview, filter, dataview

I have a VB.NET 2010 application that loads data from SQL Server to a `datagridview` through `adapter.fill()`. When I update the database it works fine but my problem is that when i use the dataview to filter the data based on combobox selection the method `adapter.update(table)` does not work!

Is there away to do it with the filter applied?

```
Private Sub cmbDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged(...) 
        Handles cmbDepartment.SelectedIndexChanged 
    Dim filter As String 
    Try 
        lblDepartmentId.Text =   ds.Tables("department").Rows(cmbDepartment.SelectedIndex)(0) 
        filter = "dprtId = " & lblDepartmentId.Text 
        dvSection = New DataView(ds.Tables("section"), filter, "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows) 
        table = dvSection.ToTable 
        dgvSections.DataSource = table 
    Catch ex As Exception 
        MsgBox(Err.Description) 
    End Try 
 End Sub

Private Sub btnSaveDepartment_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
        Handles btnSaveDepartment.Click 
    Dim cbDep As SqlCommandBuilder 
    Dim numRows As Integer 
    Try cbDep = New SqlCommandBuilder(daDep) 
        Me.Validate() numRows = daDep.Update(ds.Tables("section")) 
        MsgBox(numRows & " Rows affected.") 
    Catch ex As Exception 
        MsgBox(Err.Description) 
    End Try 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show your code and try to explain more clearly what you are trying to do. In particular - where are you applying the filter? What are you expecting the update call to do? It sounds like you want update to retrieve data - this is what fill is for. I've tried applying a filter to a bindingsource and it works fine, still allowing me to use update to update the database.

Comment: dear Mr. David, thank you very much for your reply. I will make myself clear. I have departments and sections. in the combobox i have list of departments and the sections will be displayed in the datagridview. see the following code for filtering and updating:

Comment: Private Sub cmbDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged(...)Handles cmbDepartment.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim filter As String
        Try
            lblDepartmentId.Text = ds.Tables("department").Rows(cmbDepartment.SelectedIndex)(0)
            filter = "dprtId = " & lblDepartmentId.Text
            dvSection = New DataView(ds.Tables("section"), filter, "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            table = dvSection.ToTable
            dgvSections.DataSource = table

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description)
        End Try
    End Sub

Comment: Private Sub btnSaveDepartment_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveDepartment.Click

        Dim cbDep As SqlCommandBuilder
        Dim numRows As Integer

        Try
            cbDep = New SqlCommandBuilder(daDep)
            Me.Validate()
            numRows = daDep.Update(ds.Tables("section"))
            MsgBox(numRows & " Rows affected.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description)
        End Try
    End Sub

Comment: I've given an answer below - tested it in C# but should work fine in VB.Net. Also, when you provide code you are able to edit your own question so place the code in the question. This makes it a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are currently doing your filtering is by creating a new DataTable and binding this to your DataGridView data source. This breaks the association between the original DataSet and that table so when you call Update your changes are not recovered.

Try changing to something like the code below instead (I've left out the try catch blocks, they don't change the idea that fixes your problem).

When you first set the data source to the grid set it to a form level private dvSection field:

```
Public Class Form1

    ' Here we declare some class level variables. 
    'These are visible to all members of the class

    Dim dvSection As DataView
    Dim tableAdapter As New DataSet1TableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter()
    Dim ds As New DataSet1()


    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

       ' We fill our dataset - in this case using a table adapter
        tableAdapter.Fill(ds.Customers)
        dvSection = ds.Customers.DefaultView

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dvSection

    End Sub

    ' Here is the code to filter.
    ' Note how I refer to the class level variable dvSection
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim filter As String 

        lblDepartmentId.Text =   ds.Tables("department").Rows(cmbDepartment.SelectedIndex)(0) 

        filter = "dprtId = " & lblDepartmentId.Text 
        dvSection.RowFilter = filter 

        dvSection.RowFilter = filter

    End Sub

    ' And here is the update code referring to the class level table adapter
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        tableAdapter.Update(ds.Customers)
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

One other approach that might make things easier is to introduce a binding source and set the filter on that. Either was should work fine however.

Comment: thank you very much Mr. David for your assist, it works perfect, But an other issue pops up. when i select from the combobox filtering does not work. Any idea? Sorry maybe I am annoying you

Comment: @user1548974 so long as you are referring to the same object when you reference dvSection and so long as this object is the data source for the DataGridView, then applying a row filter to dvSection should work. Have you made dvSection a class (form) level field?

Comment: Dear Mr. David, thanks again. I solved this issue this way:              Private Sub cmbDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged(...) 
        Handles cmbDepartment.SelectedIndexChanged 
    Dim filter As String dvSection =           ds.Tables("section").DefaultView;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dvSection; 
    Try 
        lblDepartmentId.Text =   ds.Tables("department").Rows(cmbDepartment.SelectedIndex)(0) 
        filter = "dprtId = " & lblDepartmentId.Text 
        dvSection.RowFilter = filter 
    Catch ex As Exception 
        MsgBox(Err.Description) 
    End Try 
End Sub

Comment: @user1548974 glad you have this working - it looks like your code is the same as mine. If it is then mark my answer as accepted so people know it works. If it isn't, post the code as your own answer. Comments on StackOverflow are not the place for code, they are hard to read and don't stand out well when people search for help.

Comment: @user1548974 ah - just spotted the difference (code in comments is hard to read) using a local copy of the default view and applying the filter there is functionally the same as my suggestion of placing this in a class level field. They should work the same. Are you clear on the various scopes in VB.net code? As I said, VB.Net is not my main language so there could be a reason why yours needs to work. When I have a minute I'll mock both up on my computer.

Comment: dear Mr. David, I am happy to hear that from you. I am new to stackoverflow.com and not very familiar with the proper way. I do not know how do you paste your here like the way it look. also when i find your solution workks with me i always post my feedback about it. I am also a bit new to VB.Net and not familiar with your other suggestion to solve the problem

Comment: @user1548974 I've edited my code to show what I mean about class level variables

Comment: dear Mr. David, I got your point and its working perfect. Thanks a lot for your assist